# How to interpret the properties of an S/MIME certificate?

Tags: x509, smime

When parsing an S/MIME certificate, there are a lot of variations and possible combinations, especially of the *Key Usage* and *Extended Key Usage* fields. It's not easy to understand what exactly they mean, how they mutually influence their meanings, and in what order to interpret them best.

How to interpret these properly in order to determine if the certificate can be used for encrypting or signing emails or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, I've finally determined the following decision matrix of how to properly interpret an S/MIME certificate's properties:

| Case | a | b | c | d | e | f | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Extension *Extended Key Usage* exists? | Y | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Extension *Extended Key Usage* marked critical? | Y | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| *Extended Key Usage* has value *Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)*? | N | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Extension *Key Usage* exists? | - | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y | N |
| Extension *Key Usage* marked critical? | - | Y | Y | Y | Y | N | - |
| *Key Usage* has value *keyEncipherment*? | - | Y | Y | N | N | - | - |
| *Key Usage* has value *digitalSignature*? | - | Y | N | Y | N | - | - |
| → Certificate can be used to encrypt |  | x | x |  |  | x | x |
| → Certificate can be used to sign |  | x |  | x |  | x | x |

- Extension Extended Key Usage is OID 2.5.29.37
- Extension Key Usage is OID 2.5.29.15

---

**How to read the decision table**

Just in case your are not familiar with decision tables, this is how to read it:

1. start with case a
2. go down to the first Y or N value (dashes mean not relevant)
3. check the condition (question and answer)
4. if it is true, continue down vertically
5. if it is false, continue to the right horizontally
6. repeat until all conditions are true
7. do down in the same column to see the results

**Example**

Case a in pseudo code

```
if exists(ExtensionExtendedKeyUsage) and isExtensionExtendedKeyUsageCritical == true and ExtendedKeyUsageValue == "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4"
    useForEncryption = false
    useForSigning = false
end-if
```

Comment: If you have additional information about the question, please use Edit button in the original question.

Comment: @Hello That’s not additional information about the question - it’s my answer.